# Understanding why the angle of reflection equals the angle of incidence in the following picture

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Consider the picture where a particle moves inside a closed disk and reflects specularly from the boundary as per the angle of incidence equals the angle of reflection rule. This will probably be a trivial question, but by what geometric tools can you argue that $\alpha_0 = \alpha_1$? The particle starts at the point $\varphi_0$ with an initial angle of $\alpha_0$ to the circle's tangent line at $\varphi_0$. The point $\varphi_1$ is given by $\varphi_1 = \varphi_0 + \vartheta \mod 2\pi$.

[image: Reflections]

Comment: Triangle with angle $\theta$ is isosceles, and tangents are perpendicular to radiuses, then angle $\alpha_0$ is congruent to angle vertical with $\alpha_1$. Both $\alpha_0$ and $\alpha_1$ are equal to $\theta/2$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu I see, the crucial observation is that the normals to $\varphi_0$ and $\varphi_1$ are collinear with the radius of the circle.